# Is there a way to retrigger event propigation i stopped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate a form when the submit button is clicked. In the validation function the first thing I do is stop the event propigation otherwise I risk the chance of the form submitting before the validation has been done. If validation is successful though then I'd like to continue event propigation so it's handled accordingly. Looking around though it doesn't seem you can do this which raises the question of how to handle this? My first thought is to stop propigation only upon a failure to validate, but as I already mentioned because events are processed simultaniousy if the validation function has not finished then I risk the chance of, well, it not finishing.

Comment: JavaScript event processing is single-threaded. What makes you think that events are going to be processed simultaneously? Are you doing the validation in a web worker?

Comment: are we supposed to guess what your code looks like? Tried polishing my crystal ball but that didn't work

Comment: Hmm... I could swear I've had problems with that in the past, but maybe I'm making a false assumption, I'll try it the way I mentioned then. I didn't post the code because it seemed so simple there wasn't a point.

Comment: you can use the little known thingy called "synthetic events" to fire another event identical tot he original one http://www.itworld.com/nl/javascript/05072002